# Import GDAL_TRANSLATE IMAGE GOES-13

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, georeferencing, satellite

I have this questions, how to Import by GDAL_TRANSLATE IMAGE GOES-13?
Whats is possible projection?

```
Files: 1501201445G13I01.TIF
Size is 14400, 12001
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=
GOES 13 Imager frame  78 at UTC 14:45:22.252 day 020 of 2015
Vis pixels :   4009, 24840    lines :   2621, 13440
Vis Lon    : 999999,999999 Lat   : 999999,999999
Imager ch1:count(0,1023) => [(albdo-0)/0.4]^1 =Uchar> (0,255)
(xscale,yscale) => (0.571429,1)
Vis pixels:  3650,  28850 lines:  2250,  14250
(xstride,ystride) => (1.75,1)
IMC status:      1
nadir pixel,line:  15352,  8050
Ref lon,d,lat,yaw:  -74.99990305,   42164.17478,         0,         0
Attitude roll,pitch,yaw:          0,         0,         0
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=255
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,12001.0)
Upper Right (14400.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (14400.0,12001.0)
Center      ( 7200.0, 6000.5)
Band 1 Block=14400x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok So!!!!!!!!!!
After much surfing the internet this is my solution!!!!!

First Import Image By GDAL_TRANSLATE by gcp.... 18

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4296 -gcp 10547.5 6349.09 -35.5741 -5.12046 -gcp 7506.62 9893.9 -64.3137 -42.9533 -gcp 7003.35 8905.9 -71.6272 -30.2687 -gcp 7175.47 7782.99 -70.3186 -18.4332 -gcp 6549.32 7301.56 -76.3004 -13.8008 -gcp 6139 4980.99 -79.9906 7.50016 -gcp 7125.8 8285.99 -70.6283 -23.5018 -gcp 7080.98 8623.37 -70.9428 -27.0953 -gcp 9846.57 8073.4 -40.9775 -21.9802 -gcp 7329.82 10163.9 -65.9988 -47.0662 -gcp 6807.66 9825.39 -73.5022 -41.8444 -gcp 7493.1 9744.75 -64.7506 -40.8024 -gcp 6798 9691.1 -73.7083 -39.9521 -gcp 7493.53 9857.26 -64.596 -42.4342 -gcp 6667.89 10185.6 -75.008 -46.6139 -gcp 7379.87 10035 -65.6839 -45.0365 -gcp 7192.07 8081.06 -70.0554 -21.424 -gcp 7059.36 7668.52 -71.441 -17.3875 -gcp 7143.17 8244.2 -70.4962 -23.073 1501201445G13I01.TIF 1501201445G13I01_tmp.TIF....
```

Second Registration by GDALWARP  1501201445G13I01_tmp.TIF....

```
gdalwarp -r bilinear -tps -co COMPRESS=LZW 1501201445G13I01_tmp.TIF 1501201445G13I01_tmpGeor.TIF
```

Third  Create Subset image with LZW Compress!!!

```
gdal_translate -projwin -97.0 0.0 -48.0 -54.0 -of GTiff  -co COMPRESS=LZW 1501201445G13I01_tmpGeor.TIF 1501201445G13I01_tmpGeorSubset.TIF...
```

I hope all GOES are same dimension!!!!!!!!!!!!!